# Another way to detect filetype besides autocmd in .vimrc?

Tags: vimrc

So I decided to to go through Damian Conway's (a well known Perl programmer) .vimrc setup as a way to get more familiar with vim and how it works. His first line is this:

`autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead  *.t                     setfiletype perl`

But there is no line like this in the file:

`autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead  *.pl                     setfiletype perl`

the .vimrc file also does not have a `:filetype on` command.

I'm curious to know: is there is some other method to get vim to automatically recognize what kind of file is getting worked on? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim recognises common file extensions by default, that's why you don't need to take care of `.*pl`.

The relevant code is in `filetype.vim` in Vim's program folder – go take a look.

Interestingly, the code for `.pl` is slightly more complicated than your line as it distinguishes between Prolog and Perl.

Comment: Yeah, what was confusing me is I did not have filetype detection turned on and so the file was not getting recognized as *.pl. I learned that once I turned that on and reloaded the file, the file was then automatically recognized as a perl file. Thanks.